# Правильный тип для String int double boolean

Tags: java, sql, база-данных, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Задача стоит в проектировании БД для интернет магазина.

У каждого товара есть набор характеристик (связь многие ко многим разбивается через промежуточную табличку).
У сущности "характеристика" есть кроме id еще String name и ??? value

Вопрос в том, какой лучше тип выбрать для value ?? пока склоняюсь к типу String, в который можно писать все вышеперечисленные типы.
Еще есть мысли по поводу не заморачиваться и написать туда Object или Serializible.

С точки зрения проектирования какое решение будет правильнее?

Spring Boot (Spring JPA)

Comment: Если "не заморачиваться", то боюсь и результат будет соответсвующий. А если вы заведете перемнную value  типа интерфейса для сериализации данных Serializible, то есть основания полагать, что и Spring JPA вместе с Hibernate жестко поставите в тупик. Spring Boot (Spring JPA) - это разные вещи, не думаю, что скобки уместны. Тип value зависит от того, что вы туда собираетесь писать. Если описание товара - стринг, продуктовый номер - лонг либо инт  и т.д. Формулировка вопроса не позволяет дать ответ.

Comment: Тогда уточню несколько. Есть различные товары и наборы характеристик у них различны. Но у похожих товаров характеристики могут повторяться. Например эл. мощность, она может быть 5Вт как у чайника так и у кофеварки и утюга (к примеру) и у нее числовое значение, но у чайника кроме мощности например есть объем, тоже число, и цвет - слово. Параметры заранее не определены. А что касается скобок - имел в виду что в рамках приложения на Boot используется JPA. Serializible тип инициализировать можно любым реализующим классом и потом приводить, но мне такой вариант не очень нравится.

Comment: Другими словами какой тип для всех перечисленных является общим

Comment: Это все легко записывается в текстовом виде, следовательно, используйте стринг. А когда у вас возникает непреодолимое желание затолкать что-то в переменную типа Object, задумайтесь над тем, зачем придумали строгую типизацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Еще есть мысли по поводу не заморачиваться и написать туда Object или Serializible.

А заморочиться придется...

Это ровно та задача, которая стоит перед любым разработчиком универсальной структуры данных. Путь известен и проторен не одним десятком прогеров, включая и меня самого. Основные положения:

1. Типизация (без него никуда), с основными типами: целое, с плавающей точкой, булевая, дата, строка. Ну может еще что-то.
2. Реализация типа на уровне класса

Если подробнее то примерно так (простейшая реализация для двух типов строка и целое число):

```
abstract class MyType {
    abstract void setValue(int value);
    abstract void setValue(String value);
    abstract String getValue();
}
class MyTypeString extends MyType {
   private String valueString=null; 

   @Override
   void setValue(int value) {
        valueString=new StringBuilder().append(value).toString();
   }

   @Override
   void setValue(String value) {
        valueString=value;
   }

   @Override
   String getValue() {
      return value;
   }
}

class MyTypeInt extends MyType {
   private Integer valueInt=null; 

   @Override
   void setValue(int value) {
        valueInt=value;
   }

   @Override
   void setValue(String value) {
        try {
           int val=Integer.parseInt(value);
           valueInt=new Integer(val);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
           valueInt=null;
        }
   }

   @Override
   String getValue() {
      return new StringBuilder().append(valueInt).toString();
   }
}
```

Comment: Интересный вариант, но в итоге мы приходим к тому что все равно данные мы храним как строки

Comment: Данные храним не строками, а объектами: `String, Integer, Double, Date` и т.д.

Comment: Sorry, с телефона не увидел, увидел только что методы get возвращают оба строку. Получается тогда для не строк каждый раз парсить. Но в бд с числами можно будет как с числами работать и места они соответственно займут.

Comment: Ну это же только макет. Можно же сделать метод `getValueObject()` возвращающий объект или `getValueInt()` возвращающий целое значение ну и т.д.

Comment: Ваш вариант мне кажется наиболее правильным.Спасибо

Comment: Вам спасибо также. P.S. имейте ввиду, что здесь есть небольшое двойное дно - а именно использование объектов позволяет использовать сущность `Not a Value` - ну как `NaN` - когда объект равен `null`

Comment: Можно в зависимости от того какая сущность реализовать необходимые методы а остальные по default а там или null или exept что не реализовано

Answer (score 2):

Выбрать "правильнее" не получится, зависит от реализации и необходимых задач.
Как вариант, добавить таблицу справочник характеристик, в которой хранить название характеристики и её тип (например Ватт, число), а в самой характеристике хранить переменную с типом Object.
В таком случае, когда нам необходимо добавить значение на экран, можно просто воспользоваться .toString(), когда нам необходимо сделать фильтрацию (например, показать для товара ползунок с максимальным и минимальным значением (блок питания 300-1000 Ватт)) используем справочник характеристик и конвертируем значение в нужный формат.

Comment: Как вариант я рассматривал то что Вы описали, но насколько правильный такой подход с точки зрения проектирования БД и с точки зрения языка в целом ?

Comment: @Tr1nks это было лично мое мнение для реализации с использованием реляционной базы данных и Spring JPA

Comment: Я  Вас понял, спасибо, но мне хотелось бы узнать не просто мнение или мнения а какой подход правилен

Answer (score 1):

Я сталкивался с 2 вариантами реализации подобных задач.
В обоих случаях требуется завести справочник характеристик с информацией о типе значения (число, строка, дата и пр.).

**Вариант 1**
Для каждого типа значений создать отдельную таблицу `number_values(товар, характеристика, значение-число)`, `string_values(товар, характеристика, значение-строка)` и т.д.

Плюсы:

- Контроль данных на уровне БД (например, для числовой характеристики в `number_values` не получится записать строку и пр. мусор).
- Расширяемость - при добавлении нового типа данных не требуется изменять существующие сущности (нужно только создать таблицу для значений нового типа и добавить условие в общий SQL-запрос (см. далее)).

Минусы:

- Сложный общий SQL-запрос для выборки значений характеристик - нужно делать join-ы с определенной таблицей со значениями в зависимости от типа характеристики.
- Усложнение логики вставки/обновления/удаления значения характеристики - таблица также определяется в зависимости от типа характеристики (НО, учитывая, что структура таблиц со значениями одинакова, отличается только тип значения, то можно легко написать общий код).
- Нужно самостоятельно контролировать консистентность данных на предмет того, чтобы, например, по одной и той же характеристике одного товара не было записей в нескольких таблице значений разных типов.

**Вариант 2** - использовать одну разряженную таблицу `values(товар, характеристика, значение-число, значение-строка, значение-дата, ...)`, где заполнено только одно из значений.

Плюсы:

- Значения атрибутов выбираются из одной таблицы -> простой SQL-запрос
- Для каждого товара не более одного значения любой характеристики

Минусы:

- Сложность в расширении - необходимо модифицировать общую таблицу со значениями
- Хранение в одной большой таблице при большом объеме данных станет узким местом

В обоих случаях я бы советовал вам в результатах выборки запроса возвращать типизированные значения, а уже на уровне бизнес-логики проводить определенные манипуляции.

Comment: А с какой целью тогда используются справочники значений? Ведь зная из какой таблицы или из какого столбца значение мы а точнее за нас создается соответствующий объект.

Comment: И почему бы тогда характеристику не разбить на 2 подтаблицы [Имя_характеристики] и [Значение_характеристики]  а в самой характеристике хранить 2 id из этих таблиц, ну или таблиц значение характеристики может быть не 1 а по кол-ву значений и тогда хранить id имени и id значения и метку из какой он таблицы. Программно реализовывать это через наследование и мучаться с тем чтоб оно заработало.